# Is there any way how to get data before utf8 encoded in pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

Using PGSQL, I had query error like

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xea 0x3c 0x68
```

when I was just using SELECT statements.

```
SELECT id, data, test FROM t_example WHERE id = 'hello';
-- Error!
```

And I have found that the query goes well without the 'data' column.

```
SELECT id, test FROM t_example WHERE id = 'hello';
-- Works well...
```

So it seems the cause of the error probably is on the data column. I want to check or view what kind of text is inside the data column, but it seems I cant take it because the SELECT query itself is not working here because of the encoding problem...

Is there anyway I can check the data inside without encoding or whatever please.
But the thing is that I don't want to do dumping or migration because the database is too huge to do that. Please let me know if there is something easy and fast way to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Does `select *` work? Can you also try changing your client encoding config `set client_encoding to 'latin1'` or `SET client_encoding = 'WIN1252'` and run your select statement?

Comment: @Equinox Thanks for the comment. select * doesnt work. Im not sure changing encoding settings is totally safe because its actual service server in my company.

Comment: Can you take a backup of the table and work on it? Otherwise you probably need to look at the file from which you are loading the data. More often than not it would probably be an encoding mismatch between file and table. 

Convert the fie to UTF-8 first and then load the data

Comment: `set client_encoding` only effects the local session.  What does "totally safe" mean here?  Your data is *already* broken.